# Finding and replacing the last space at or before nth character works with sed but not awk, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a string in a test.csv file like this:

```
here is my string
```

when I use sed it works just as I expect:

```
cat test.csv | sed -r 's/^(.{1,9}) /\1,/g'
here is,my string
```

Then when I use awk it doesn't work and I'm not sure why:

```
cat test.csv | awk '{gsub(/^(.{1,9}) /,","); print}'
,my string
```

I need to use awk because once I get this figured out I will be selecting only one column to split into two columns with the added comma.  I'm using extended regex with sed, "-r" and was wondering how or if it's supported with awk, but I don't know if that really is the problem or not.

Comment: Looks like the awk line is missing a capture group in the replacement that was in the sed line.

Comment: Your command returns `,my string` and not `here is my string` *(unchanged)*. awk doesn't have the backreference feature by default. But you can use gawk and `gensub` in place of `gsub`. *(take care that `gensub` doesn't change a string in place but returns the replaced string)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:  Thanks you and jaypal were right on the money!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk **does not** support back references in `gsub`. If you are on GNU awk, then `gensub` can be used to do what you need.

```
echo "here is my string" | awk '{print gensub(/^(.{1,9}) /,"\\1,","G")}'
here is,my string
```

Note the use of double `\` inside the quoted replacement part. You can read more about `gensub` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1).

Comment: Thanks to you and Casimir!  I tried using gensub before I posted but had an error and then I tried your solution and realized the was do to not having GNU awk (gawk) installed, but I also would've missed the double ' \ ' so thanks for clearing up the errors of my ways!

Comment: @lukeaw You're welcome. I'm glad you got it sorted out! Cheers!